# Check if User Exist then display else hidden

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

i got some issue here regarding the if else condition whereby i set if the user exist and it shall display the credit "个人余额：0 CNY" else if user not exist then display "用户不存在".

Kindly advise as my code only working "用户不存在". but if userExist it do nothing.

HTML :

```
<span class="js-fc-fu-ma-tip text-danger hidden">用户不存在</span>
          <div class="js-fc-fu-ma-tip-userCredit inline-block text-danger hidden">
            <strong>个人余额：<span id="__user_balance">0</span></strong>
            <span style="float:right;margin-left:5px;">CNY</span> 
          </div>
```

BackBone.js

```
checkUserExistHandler: function(e){
      var self = this;
      var data = {
        username:$(e.currentTarget).val()
      };
      this.checkUserExistXhr(data).fail(function(){
      }).done(function(res){
        if(res.result===0){
          self.$('.js-fc-fu-ma-tip').addClass('hidden');
          self.$('.js-fc-fu-ma-tip-userCredit').addClass('hidden');
        }else{
          self.$('.js-fc-fu-ma-tip').removeClass('hidden');
          self.$('.js-fc-fu-ma-tip-userCredit').removeClass('hidden');
        }
      });

    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an solution as i wrong replace the logic of the checking :

Here the answer :

```
checkUserExistHandler: function(e){
      var self = this;
      var data = {
        username:$(e.currentTarget).val()
      };
      this.checkUserExistXhr(data).fail(function(){
      }).done(function(res){
        if(res.result===0){
          self.$('.js-fc-fu-ma-tip').addClass('hidden');
          self.$('.js-fc-fu-ma-tip-userCredit').removeClass('hidden');
        }else{
          self.$('.js-fc-fu-ma-tip').removeClass('hidden');
          self.$('.js-fc-fu-ma-tip-userCredit').addClass('hidden');

        }
      });

    },
```